# Finding and proving the optimal port/socket/thread ratio

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, port

How do I figure out and prove the optimal port/socket/thread ratio for my application?

At the moment I am considering something like this:

Each thread handles all the traffic of a single port, each client gets their own socket, and the sockets are split between the available ports, and thus threads.  This solution is based on the assumption that I should create approximately one thread per CPU core, and that sockets are fairly cheap to open.  Is this a good solution, and more importantly how do I mathematically prove that this, or any other solution, is a good one?

I know I can write a sample program for every solution and test the results, but I would much prefer a mathematical proof over an empirical one, especially where the test is done on a machine that does not reflect the server hardware and configuration.

I don't have much experience with ports and sockets, and I am having a tough time finding information to answer my question.  The best resources I could find so far are these Stack Overflow questions:

- [Forcing multiple threads to use multiple CPUs when they are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223072/how-do-i-optimize-for-multi-core-and-multi-cpu-computers-in-java)
- [When Should I Use Threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857184/when-should-i-use-threads)
- [What is the difference between a port and a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket)

If I simply overlooked someting, or are misunderstanding the way ports, sockets and threads are/should be used I will be quite content with a simple "rtfm:[link]" answer to point me in the right direction.  However If you are feeling magnanimous and provide me with a good explanation I will be much obliged.

Comment: Don't "lock" things to threads unless you have a very good reason. Otherwise, you force extra context switches (because the "wrong" thread was running) for no reason.

Comment: I think most of the choices always depend on what you're trying to achieve. We have no idea what your application will be doing. When working with client/server models, what i do is listen on an single port/socket, then, when the client connects, i create a thread that will exist only to serve that specific client, while the original socket will stay listening to serve other clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use non-blocking NIO, the optimal performance is 1 Thread / core. The reason for this is very simple:

- With non-blocking IO, whenever there is work available, it will be executed by 1 available thread at full speed (as no blocking).
- You can never exceed 100% CPU usage.