# RTOS and using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, keil

So I'm a little bit confused about the best way to form threads for a game I've implemented. The game is very simple, you must maneuver your spaceship to dodge incoming walls.

At the moment my code just loops through until the spaceship has blown up. Represented by this while loop (`notBlownUp()` returns false if game is over):

```
while(notBlownUp()) {   
    osSignalSet(tid_taskDisplay, 1U);   
}
```

So this sets the signal for the `taskDisplay()`

```
void taskDisplay(void const *argument){

    for (;;) {
        osSignalWait(1U, osWaitForever);
        drawEverything();
        osSignalSet(tid_taskWall, 1U);
        osSignalSet(tid_taskSpaceship, 1U);
    }
}

void taskDisplay(void const *argument);
osThreadId tid_taskDisplay; 
osThreadDef(taskDisplay, osPriorityAboveNormal, __FI, 0);
```

And all `taskWall` and `taskSpaceship` do is update the spaceship dependent on the user input:

```
void taskSpaceship(void const *argument){

    for (;;) {
        osSignalWait(1U, osWaitForever);
        updateSpaceship();
    }
}
osThreadId tid_taskSpaceship;  
osThreadDef(taskSpaceship, osPriorityAboveNormal, __FI, 0);
```

The `taskWall` is exactly the same as `taskSpaceship` just updating the wall instead.

My question is, what is the point of having threads when it is just doing one after another? Or am I just doing this completely wrong?

The code is essentially executing in this order:

**taskDisplay -> taskWall -> taskSpaceship -> taskDisplay -> taskWall -> taskSpaceship**

To me, the sequential-ness of it makes me think I'm using threads wrong!

Comment: You don't actually need to use threads if your program is purely sequential. That said, threading still gives some nice abstraction and can help simplify parts of the code if used correctly; if used incorrectly, it can make things much more complicated. A quick google search for "why use threads" gave me some interesting results, including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857184/when-should-i-use-threads) SO post. Edit: and [this](https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/FUNDAMENTALS/threads.html) college-level cs class webpage.

Comment: Yeah, see that's what I'm thinking. But really the program is purely sequential because I wanted to create the program then transition to threads where I can, any ideas how I could make the transition? @mgarey And I know I don't necessarily need to, but for learning purposes I would like to. I believe `taskSpaceship` and `taskWall` could be done asynchronously somehow.

Comment: In your code, wouldn't `taskWall` and `taskSpaceship` be executed in parallel?

Comment: wait really? I just assumed it did one after the other? @agbinfo

Comment: It signals the first, then the second thread. The 2 tasks can now exit their `osTaskWait`. Both threads can execute at the same time. Also, your main thread seems to be a busy loop which means that `taskDisplay` will call `drawEverything` immediately - while the other 2 tasks are running unless they have completed.

Comment: So would this method of doing it be considered poor practice? what other way could I do it @agbinfo

Comment: Event driven and multi-threading are not poor practices. There are many ways to accomplish a goal. Busy loops, however, are generally a bad idea; that part you may want to take a second look at.

Comment: What could I change the busy loop with @agbinfo have you got any references I could look at or an example?

Comment: A busy loop can easily be replaced with a ```sem_wait(semaphore_pointer)``` or ```mutex_lock(mutex_pointer)```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want event-driven code, something like:

clock tick event -> Game physics updates moving pieces based on elapsed time

keyboard event -> Process user input

That way the event-driven threads can execute in any order.

Comment: Might mean some refactoring of what is in each thread.  Also your initialization routine needs to set up asynchronous clock and keyboard events.

Comment: I don't have keyboard events this is for a microcontroller

Comment: So what is your user input?

Comment: touching the screen!

Comment: Then that's what you make as your async event for the "Process user input" thread.