# i'm so confused about Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I read a lot about threads but don't understand yet :( let me explain to you what I have learned about threads. all we are working on such as codes any thing worked on UI thread or Main thread right? After that what happens if we call runOnUiThread? and my other question how do we know it's Time to use a new thread? I mean how do we understand we are working on another thread or replace or code in the new thread?

I know this is an unclear question but I don't understand as well. Please help me Thanks, john.

Comment: your questions are completely unclear. but for more information , visit the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857184/when-should-i-use-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer. Actually Android has Main Thread (also called as UI Thread) and other thread.

Main Thread is basically for showing UI and other thread is for processing other big processes such as connecting to the server, etc.

`runOnUiThread` is called when you want to move from other thread to main thread. It is needed since only main thread can show/display result on UI. So when you have done some process on other thread, and you want to display the result on the apps, you need to show it on main thread by calling `runOnUiThread`.

We working on other thread only if it is a big or lengthy process like taking data from the server, load data, etc. And we move from other thread to main thread whenever we want to show some UI result.

Comment: As such, the main thread is also **sometimes** called the UI thread. That's what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) says.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use   `AsyncTask<>` class. You'll need to override three functions.

1. doInBackGround(...) : The codes that gets executed in background thread.
2. onPreExecute(..) : code that gets executed before background thread
   completes executing like displaying progress bars, etc.
3. onPostExecute(...): Code that gets executed after background thread
   has completed running. Perform task like updating UI in here

Answer (score -1):

One general rule of thumb is: Don't use multithreading if you don't need to. Multithreading is always error-prone, and in many situations there's no benefit. Basically, you start a new thread whenever you execute a lengthy operation (i.e. some extensive computation like image processing) that would block the main thread for some time, so the application would become unresponsive.

Comment: it's not true at all. How NOT to use multi threading on android and have an efficient application? It's not a good practice to avoid concurrency just because it may get difficult to be used.

Comment: This is not what I intended to say. My point was that multithreading should be avoided if there's no benefit of concurrency. It's a common misconception that multithreading is always a good thing. It's only a good thing if there's something that can be parallelized, i.e. two or more computations that are independent of each other, like waiting for a device to become ready, or lengthy data processing.